# Como retornar de uma tabela associativa o objeto completo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

O código abaixo retorna somente os ID's de seus respectivos relacionamentos, preciso que ao invés de retornar `user_id` e `role_id` retorne o objeto `user` e `role` com os dados do registro. De uma olhada em meu código:

```
class Dispute < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :users_with_roles, through: :roles, source: :users_roles
  ...
end
```

O retorno atual é este:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<UsersRole user_id: "6c566300-14b8-4099-949d-a06e058cc68f", role_id: "216fdc1d-d4d5-4f49-a80d-cb73f8648491">]>
```

O código da Model de relacionamento:

```
class UsersRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Agradeço qualquer dica para resolução desta questão. Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o include? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations

Comment: Onde vc vai usar o objeto? É api ou algo do tipo?

Comment: @Rmobdick é uma alternativa, obrigado pela dica. @alex-takitani consegui resolver através do serializer chamando o elemento `user` e `role` diretamente. Agora não sei se é a melhor alternativa. É uma api e estou utilizando serializer.

Comment: Serializer resolve, até mesmo o proprio to_json, veja: https://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegue efetivar o resultado que desejo utilizando Serializer. Primeiro defini no serializer os relacionamentos:

```
class Dispute::UsersRolesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :user, serializer: Dispute::UserSerializer
  belongs_to :role, serializer: Dispute::RoleSerializer
end
```

E logo em seguida defini quais os dados que desejo para apresentação:

```
class Dispute::UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end

class Dispute::RoleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

Está foi a forma que encontrei. Provavelmente existam outras alternativas para está questão.